# How do i hook a batch file to maven?

Tags: maven, batch-file, hook

i need to hook or attach a batch file to maven

so if lets say i type 
   mvn package

and the there were no errors then a batch file i created would start running.

is there a way of doing something like that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do that with the [`maven-exec-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and linking it with the package phase:

```
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>runbatchfile</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <executable>c:\path\to\file.bat</executable>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

With this configuration : your batch file will be execute just after the default goal associated with the package phase.

Comment: Thx ben, how can i make sure it will run ONLY if the goal encountered no errors ?

Comment: If you have an exception prior to the batch execution, the maven lifecycle will be stopped. Since the custom goals are executed after the default goals: if something goes wrong in a previous phase or even the package phase (during execution of default goal): mvn will issue a Build Failure and your batch file won't be executed. (the best way to convince you is to try it... but I've no idea on how triggering an error in the package phase ???)

Comment: is there a way to trigger the batch file using maven goal after the deploy phase?

Comment: @Lucy just replace <phase>package</phase> by <phase>deploy</phase>

Comment: I tried that but nothing is happening..any reason why?? I'm using tomcat plugin to deploy a war file to localhost so I want to run the batch file after the war file has been deployed.

Comment: @Lucy. ok you are talking about the deploy goal of the maven-tomcat-plugin (i.e. not the maven deploy phase). tomcat-plugin is executed after the package phase, so just bind the exec to the package phase and declare it AFTER the tomcat plugin in the pom.xml.