# maven-antrun-plugin on windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, maven

I am trying to get my maven project to work on both windows 7 and ubuntu 13.04. In a pom.xml file I use maven-antrun-plugin to call  [scons](http://www.scons.org/) which I have installed on both my linux and windows machine. On both os's I have verified that I can run `scons` from shell/cmd so its on the PATH. The pom  looks like this:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-scons</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target name="run-scons">
                                <exec executable="scons" dir="${basedir}/../../../" failonerror="true">
                                    <arg value="-j4" />
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But when I build on windows7 I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (run-scons) on project my-project: An Ant BuildExcept
ion has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scons" (in directory "C:\Users\u\samples"): CreateProcess error=2,
The system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="C:\Users\u\samples...." executable="scons" failonerror="true">
```

If I open a cmd and run it from there I get:

```
C:\Users\u\samples\>scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Using configuration: scons/win32mscdbg.py
```

Why can't I call `scons` from the antrun plugin? If I specify the full path to scons on windows it works (eg. C:\Python26\Scripts\scons.bat) but that is a no-go since developers are only required to have scons in their path, but can decide the location themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would maven [exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) make a difference?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-scons</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>scons</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/../../../</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-j4</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I can't test this, but it looks like you *can* run bat files ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181226/679982), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872594/679982)) as "executables" in maven as opposed to ant where you run the shell with the bat file as argument (read [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) under win users). The linked examples are all with absolute path, which is not your case. I advise to try and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This approach has worked for me with other commands.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>run-scons</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <!-- TODO: fill in the correct os property value -->
          <exec executable="scons" dir="${basedir}/../../../" failonerror="true" 
                os="<os.name property value for Ubuntu>"
            <arg value="-j4" />
          </exec>

          <exec executable="cmd" dir="${basedir}/../../../" failonerror="true" 
                os="Windows 7"
            <arg line="/C scons /> 
            <arg value="-j4" />  <!-- /j4 on windows?  never used scons -->
          </exec>
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```